# Avoid notifying a std::condition_variable if it's unnecessary

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am writing a threadpool. A main thread gives a job to worker threads by setting an atomic pointer. The worker checks the pointer, and if it is `nullptr`, it waits on a `std::condition_variable` to avoid burning CPU unnecessarily. If not, it runs the job.

The main thread therefore calls `notify_one()` on the worker's condition variable after giving it a job, even if the worker is currently running a job, and is not waiting (i.e. the next loop would pick up the next job).

Here's the original code:

```cpp
struct Worker
{
    bool wake_up {false};
    std::condition_variable condition;
    std::mutex mutex;

    std::atomic<Job*> next_job {nullptr};
    std::atomic<bool> stop {false};

    void run()
    {
        while (! stop.load())
        {
            auto* job = next_job.exchange(nullptr);

            if (job != nullptr)
                job->run();
            else
                wait_for_job();
        }
    }

    void wait_for_job()
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
        if (! wake_up)
            condition.wait(lock, [this] { return wake_up; });
    }

    bool push_job (Job* job)
    {
        Job* expected = nullptr;

        if (w.next_job.compare_exchange_weak(expected, job))
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(w.mutex);
            w.wake_up = true;
            w.condition.notify_all();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Worker w;
    std::thread t ([&w] { w.run(); });

    // The main thread runs an event loop, where
    // certain events launch background jobs.
    // This is a stand-in for the event loop.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds (50));
        w.push_job (chooseJob());
    }

    w.stop.store(true);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

This works reasonably well, but profiling says that the main thread is spending a significant amount of time in the `notify_one()` call, and I was wondering if I can reduce that. So I tried this (omitting `main()` since it stayed the same):

```cpp
enum class WaitState
{
    waiting,
    running,
    woken
};

struct Worker
{
    std::atomic<WaitState> waiting {WaitState::running};
    std::condition_variable condition;
    std::mutex mutex;

    std::atomic<Job*> next_job {nullptr};
    std::atomic<bool> stop {false};

    void run()
    {
        while (! stop.load())
        {
            auto* job = next_job.exchange(nullptr);

            if (job != nullptr)
                job->run();
            else
                wait_for_job();
        }
    }

    void wait_for_job()
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
        auto w = WaitState::running;

        if (waiting.compare_exchange_strong(w, WaitState::waiting))
        {
            const auto stop_waiting = [this] { return waiting.load() == WaitState::woken; };
            condition.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(500), stop_waiting);
        }

        waiting.store(WaitState::running);
    }

    bool push_job (Job* job)
    {
        Job* expected = nullptr;

        if (w.next_job.compare_exchange_weak(expected, job))
        {
            std::lock_guard lock (w.mutex);

            auto w = WaitState::waiting;

            if (waiting.compare_exchange_strong (w, WaitState::woken))
                w.condition.notify_all();
        }
    }
};
```

But now my jobs don't always seem to run correctly, almost as if the worker isn't being woken at the right times any more. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `push_job`'s `job` argument is unused, is that a typo? In either case, `main` is not sleeping anywhere so its high CPU usage makes sense.

Comment: It's too complicated. It can be done with an only mutex and w/o a atomic. The worker locks a mutex at start and releases it in waiting a condition. The main loop locks a mutex, sends notify and unlocks a mutex.

Comment: This doesn’t adding the question, but `while (! stop.load())` should simply be `while (! stop)` and `waiting.store(WaitState::running);` should simply be `waiting = WaitState::running;`. There’s no need for the explicit load and store; atomics have appropriate overloaded member functions.

Comment: Note that calling `notify_one()` or notify_all()` when no thread is waiting doesn’t do anything. The condition variable doesn’t keep track of past notifications. Notifications only do something when there is a thread waiting on the condition variable.

Comment: @PeteBecker I prefer to show atomic loads/stores, they are not free and it helps me see where synchronization points are happening. As for `notify_x()` when no thread is waiting: it is actually 'free' or does it have a performance cost? In my profiles `notify_one()` is at the top of the profile, ahead of the actual work being done on the threadpool!

Comment: @Quimby Yes, that was a typo. As for main sleeping, this is a boiled-down simplified example. In reality main runs an event loop, and launches background jobs on certain events.

@273K Yes, I'm aware it can be done more simply. I was trying to find a way to avoid calling `notify()` so often because it's at the top of my profile.

Answer (score 0):

No atomic pointer is necessary.

```
struct Worker
{
    std::condition_variable condition;
    std::mutex mutex;

    Job* next_job {nullptr};
    bool stop {false};

    void run()
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
    
        while (!stop)
        {
            if (next_job)
                next_job->run();
            next_job = nullptr;
            condition.wait(lock, []{ return next_job || stop; });
        }
    }

    bool push_job (Job* job)
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(w.mutex);

        // If we are here, the worker thread is waiting for the condition
        // and next_job is nullptr.

        next_job = job;
        w.condition.notify_all();
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Worker w;
    std::thread t ([&w] { w.run(); });

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds (50));
        w.push_job (chooseJob());
    }

    w.stop = true;
    {
      std::lock_guard lock(w.mutex);
      w.condition.notify_all();
    }
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem with your version is that, if the worker is running a slow job, the main thread must wait for that job to complete before pushing a new job. In my version, pushing the job succeeds or fails immediately, which improves things a lot if we have multiple worker threads and we search for the first one that will accept the job.

Comment: You did not show it in your question. I could not guess, just answered the exact your question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am trying to write a performant threadpool with high throughput. My existing code is the result of profiling and tweaking.

Although my exact question was actually: 'can I avoid calling notify_one() sometimes?' as this is where my profile shows most time is now spent.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: There's a deeper problem with your design. Here's a high-level description of what you are trying to do:

```
10000 times:
    - worker thread waits for next job
    - main thread chooses a job
    - main thread "pushes" job
    - main thread waits while worker thread performs job
```

Your main thread was burning a lot of CPU cycles because it was [*busy waiting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) for the worker to finish. But what is the point of having a worker thread at all? At every moment in that loop, either one thread is waiting or the other thread is waiting. Why don't you just do this instead?

```
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        chooseJob()->run();
    };
    return 0;
}
```

That's four lines of code instead of your thirty five lines, and it gets the same job done more efficiently. There is never any reason to have multiple threads if you don't ever let more than one of them do something interesting at the same time. In both your original example, and in the example proposed by somebody else here, the main thread and the worker thread only ever *take turns* doing things. Any time you see threads taking turns, you can probably improve the program by just doing all the work in a single thread.

Comment: Are you referring to that `this_thread::sleep()` in `main()`? That is simply there for demonstrative purposes, to show that jobs will be launched at different times (triggered by certain events elsewhere), not all at once. I will clarify with a comment.

Comment: @tommaisey, Maybe I misread your code. When I read it, it  was with the expectation that the main thread _must_ somehow wait, because how would it make any sense for it _not_ to wait? There is no queue to hold a backlog of jobs. If the main thread doesn't wait, then what happens if it produces two jobs in less time than it takes for the worker to complete the first one?

Comment: Yes, sorry I think your misunderstanding is an artifact of my cut-down example. In the real application there is a queue of jobs, and `chooseJob()` picks the one with the highest priority.

If jobs are produced faster than the workers can service them, then it's a problem! They would sit in the queue, unserviced. That's why I'm trying to reduce the overhead of marshalling between the main and worker thread, to increase that throughput and make that scenario less likely.